# Having Trouble Making a RESTful API with Flask-RestX: "No operations defined in spec!" and "404"s

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask-restx

In summary, I have been following the flask restx tutorials to make an api, however none of my endpoints appear on the swagger page ("No operations defined in spec!") and I just get 404 whenever I call them

I created my api mainly following this https://flask-restx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scaling.html

I'm using python 3.8.3 for reference.

A cut down example of what I'm doing is as follows.

My question in short is, what am I missing?
Currently drawing blank on why this doesn't work.

#### Directory Structure

```
project/
  - __init__.py
  - views/
    - __init__.py
    - test.py
manage.py
requirements.txt
```

#### File Contents

**requirements.txt**

```
Flask-RESTX==0.2.0
Flask-Script==2.0.6
```

**manage.py**

```
from flask_script import Manager

from project import app


manager = Manager(app)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

**project/**init**.py**

```
from flask import Flask

from project.views import api


app = Flask(__name__)

api.init_app(app)
```

**project/views/**init**.py**

```
from flask_restx import Api, Namespace, fields


api = Api(
    title='TEST API',
    version='1.0',
    description='Testing Flask-RestX API.'
)

# Namespaces
ns_test = Namespace('test', description='a test namespace')

# Models
custom_greeting_model = ns_test.model('Custom', {
    'greeting': fields.String(required=True),
})

# Add namespaces
api.add_namespace(ns_test)
```

**project/views/test.py**

```
from flask_restx import Resource

from project.views import ns_test, custom_greeting_model


custom_greetings = list()


@ns_test.route('/')
class Hello(Resource):

    @ns_test.doc('say_hello')
    def get(self):
        return 'hello', 200


@ns_test.route('/custom')
class Custom(Resource):

    @ns_test.doc('custom_hello')
    @ns_test.expect(custom_greeting_model)
    @ns_test.marshal_with(custom_greeting_model)
    def post(self, **kwargs):
        custom_greetings.append(greeting)
        pos = len(custom_greetings) - 1

        return [{'id': pos, 'greeting': greeting}], 200
```

#### How I'm Testing & What I Expect

So going to the swagger page, I expect the 2 endpoints defined to be there, but I just see the aforementioned error.

Just using Ipython in a shell, I've tried to following calls using requests and just get back 404s.

```
import json
import requests as r

base_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/'
```

```
response = r.get(base_url + 'api/test')
response
```

```
response = r.get(base_url + 'api/test/')
response
```

```
data = json.dumps({'greeting': 'hi'})
response = r.post(base_url + 'test/custom', data=data)
response
```

```
data = json.dumps({'greeting': 'hi'})
response = r.post(base_url + 'test/custom/', data=data)
response
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### TL;DR

I made a few mistakes in my code and test:

1. Registering api before declaring the routes.
2. Making a wierd assumption about how the arguments would be passed to the `post` method.
3. Using a model instead of request parser in the `expect` decorator
4. Calling the endpoints in my testing with an erroneous `api/` prefix.

---

### In Full

I believe it's because I registered the namespace on the api before declaring any routes.

My understanding is when the api is registered on the app, the swagger documentation and routes on the app are setup at that point. Thus any routes defined on the api after this are not recognised. I think this because when I declared the namespace in the `views/test.py` file (also the model to avoid circular referencing between this file and `views/__init__.py`), the swagger documentation had the routes defined and my tests worked (after I corrected them).

There were some more mistakes in my app and my tests, which were

#### Further Mistake 1

In my app, in the `views/test.py` file, I made a silly assumption that a variable would be made of the expected parameter (that I would just magically have **greeting** as some non-local variable). Looking at the documentation, I learnt about the [RequestParser](https://flask-restx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parsing.html), and that I needed to declare one like so

```
from flask_restx import reqparse

# Parser
custom_greeting_parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
custom_greeting_parser.add_argument('greeting', required=True, location='json')
```

and use this in the `expect` decorator. I could then retrieve a dictionary of the parameters in my `post` method. with the below

```
...
    def post(self):
        args = custom_greeting_parser.parse_args()
        greeting = args['greeting']
        ...
```

The `**kwargs` turned out to be unnecessary.

#### Further Mistake 2

In my tests, I was calling the endpoint `api/test`, which was incorrect, it was just `test`. The corrected test for this endpoint is

**Corrected test for `test` endpoint**

```
import json
import requests as r

base_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/'

response = r.get(base_url + 'test')
print(response)
print(json.loads(response.content.decode()))
```

#### Further Mistake 3

The test for the other endpoint, the post, I needed to include a header declaring the content type so that the parser would "see" the parameters, because I had specified the location explictily as json. Corrected test below.

**Corrected test for `test/custom` endpoint**

```
import json
import requests as r

base_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/'

data = json.dumps({'greeting': 'hi'})
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
response = r.post(base_url + 'test/custom', data=data, headers=headers)
print(response)
print(json.loads(response.content.decode()))
```

### Corrected Code

For the files with incorrect code.

**views/**init**.py**

```
from flask_restx import Api

from project.views.test import ns_test


api = Api(
    title='TEST API',
    version='1.0',
    description='Testing Flask-RestX API.'
)


# Add namespaces
api.add_namespace(ns_test)
```

**views/test.py**

```
from flask_restx import Resource, Namespace, fields, reqparse


# Namespace
ns_test = Namespace('test', description='a test namespace')

# Models
custom_greeting_model = ns_test.model('Custom', {
    'greeting': fields.String(required=True),
    'id': fields.Integer(required=True),
})

# Parser
custom_greeting_parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
custom_greeting_parser.add_argument('greeting', required=True, location='json')


custom_greetings = list()


@ns_test.route('/')
class Hello(Resource):

    @ns_test.doc('say_hello')
    def get(self):
        return 'hello', 200


@ns_test.route('/custom')
class Custom(Resource):

    @ns_test.doc('custom_hello')
    @ns_test.expect(custom_greeting_parser)
    @ns_test.marshal_with(custom_greeting_model)
    def post(self):
        args = custom_greeting_parser.parse_args()
        greeting = args['greeting']

        custom_greetings.append(greeting)
        pos = len(custom_greetings) - 1

        return [{'id': pos, 'greeting': greeting}], 200
```